# What is manual speed and how does it change?

Tags: one-finger-death-punch-2

Just started playing OFDP2 and for some reason, even at the tutorial, the game speed was crazy. Most likely because my manual speed was like 2.5x.

Why was it set so high and how does it change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have been able to gather, *manual speed* is simply a static-ish multiplier on the speed of the game.

As [stated by the developer](https://steamcommunity.com/app/980300/discussions/0/3726075043730327186/)

> The game uses the tutorial levels to adjust the difficulty to fit the player.

(Which would explain why my speed started so fast.)

The keys to change the speed are + and - on the numpad, = and - next to backspace and d-pad up and down on a controller.

You have to be in a round to change it.

Comment: How do you change it in the Android app?